# How to identify the contents of a base64 string reported to be a "certificate"?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate

I have several variants of this certificate. The first dozen or so of the base64 characters match, then diverge. Each is exactly 640 base64 characters (so 480 bytes?). No identifying information or clues are present, other than an "id" in guid format.

If I dump this into its own file, I imagine I'll have to add the "begin certificate" header and footer to it. Do I have to do linebreaks/wrapping? Which tools can I use to identify what format this is (or at least rule them out)? My experience with this stuff doesn't go much farther than uploading a key to github or something like that, and I don't ever have any reason to look inside the files (and wouldn't see much if I did).

This (base64) value is transmitted in some xhr endpoint via xml in a  tag. I suspect it's just used to validate a signature on another file, but it seems a little out of place and I'd like to learn more about it.

```
<Certificate>
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
</Certificate>
```

This one is dated August 25th:

```
<Certificate>
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
</Certificate>
```

This one is dated August 18th:

```
<Certificate>
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
</Certificate>
```

This one is dated August 11th:

```
<Certificate>
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
</Certificate>
```

The portion of it that is `fqiMTc9TxZw+55we2D8GudFustjIp+jjxHhUomzLtd` matches for the above.

Comment: Decode the base 64 and then run the `file` command on the result. If it is a certificate you could also use the command that toppk specified with the additional `-inform DER` parameters.

Comment: Officially PEM _should_ have linebreaks in the base64; see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-2 at the end. Readers vary in their handling of overlong base64 lines; _recent_ OpenSSL (1.1.0 up) will handle your 640 chars, though it _not_ unlimited length. Note the dashes _and_ linebreaks on the BEGIN _and_ END lines are mandatory; without _all_ of those almost nothing will work. But concur with @MaartenBodewes converting to 'DER' (binary) is just as good.

Comment: file just says "data" after un-base64ing it. Now I'm even more curious.

Comment: Normally certs are public, feel free to post it by hitting [edit].

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Added it as it appears in the xml. If anyone wants me to format it I'll do that too, just not sure how is best.

Comment: I'll check, but that's not an X509
 certificate, certs start with an `M` in base 64 (as the first byte must be 0x30).

Comment: A Shannon entropy of near 7.5, which you would expect as minimum entropy for encrypted text. If it is just a public key then it is really large and probably too random. It may be encrypted.

Comment: If it's encrypted, I'm not seeing any other http traffic that would/could transmit the key to decrypt. I suppose the key might be in the app itself, but it's still weird.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes If this was encrypted, then they'd be encrypting it with the private key so everyone with the app (through the app) could decrypt it with the public. So somewhere in its install folder, there is a key there.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes `dumpasn1` would probably be a lot more useful for examining a binary blob suspected of being a certificate.

Comment: Uh, maybe. In this case the blob doesn't even start with `0x30`, so it is not a SEQUENCE or SET, so any ASN.1 tool will fail. ASN.1 dumps may detect specific non-X509 certificates that are defined using ASN.1, but it won't detect things like PGP certificates that do not. The `file` comment should properly detect those and many other forms of data.

Answer (score 1):

if it is an x509 certificate, with the appropriate header/footer, this command will display it.

```
openssl x509  -text -in path/to/filename
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspect it's x509... I mean, who would call it a certificate otherwise? But there is no header/footer, and I don't think I know all the variations of those to try each in turn.  Getting a `routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad end line` when I try to run it with BEGIN CERTIFICATE.

Comment: You would need the same line after the base 64 but with END instead of BEGIN.